# How to make the transition between two cylinders with different angles smoother?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I'm new to Blender and I want to make this transition smoother. I've already tried looking on Youtube, but nothing work's (including Boolean. I don't know why).

The transition in question:
[image: the transition in question]

Comment: Retract the edges a little, to leave a gap, and use Bridge Edge Loops?

Comment: Side note: You can also use extruded Curve objects to model pipes.

Comment: Do they have to be separate objects or can they be combined into one object?

Answer (score 2):

Join the two pipes with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, then in **Edit Mode** select the edge loop of the right pipe with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> and move it a bit to the right with <kbd>G</kbd> to make enough space for a bridge.

Select the edge loops of both ends of the pipes you want to join and go to **Edge** > **Bridge Edge Loops**. You can also move the pipes around a bit to make this transition look smoother, before or even after this operation.

[image]

You can also just use one pipe and in **Edit Mode** select the edge loop you want to extend and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> to any location where you want to bend to. Repeatedly do this to get a curve as well.

[image]